# How to change Paragraph Margin in Windows Phone 8 XAML?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

There is a RichTextBox with Paragraph inside it.
How to change margin of the inner paragraph? There is no such property.
Setting of RichTextBox.Padding to "-12,0" helps, but looks like an ugly hack.

Comment: *It is WP8 XAML, not Windows8 XAML*  This is the first time that's bitten me before.  I'd assume there is some other method for this.  +1 for the bump.

Answer (score 2):

By default RichTextBox will have a margin (12,0,12,0) for its root border element and hence the space on your left side and right side will be added by default. If you want to change the behavior you have to customize the RichTextBox template itself.

You can use this template  and avoid the additional margin being added at left and right.

```XAML
<ControlTemplate TargetType="RichTextBox">
    <Grid Background="Transparent">
        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
            <ContentControl x:Name="ContentElement" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Regards,
Mawy

Answer (score 1):

How about this option: lock also ugly, but still:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <RichTextBox>
                <Paragraph>
                    <InlineUIContainer>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="tbMargin" Margin="100,0,0,0"></TextBlock>
                    </InlineUIContainer>
                    Hi from Paragraph
                </Paragraph>               
            </RichTextBox>           
        </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another hack: (at least for margin left :)

```
<Paragraph xml:space="preserve">
    Hi from Paragraph
    Hi from Paragraph 2
</Paragraph>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set property TextIndent of Paragraph. I'll show you a sample:

```
    <RichTextBox>
        <FlowDocument>
            <Paragraph TextIndent="6"><Run Text="Paragraph 1"/></Paragraph>
            <Paragraph TextIndent="12"><Run Text="Paragraph 2"/></Paragraph>
            <Paragraph TextIndent="18"><Run Text="Paragraph 3"/></Paragraph>
            <Paragraph TextIndent="24"><Run Text="Paragraph 4"/></Paragraph>
        </FlowDocument>
    </RichTextBox>
```

This would result to this: 
[image: TextIndent of Paragraph]